# How to filter ISO DateTime objects outside the range of specific time interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, luxon

I have a list of objects with `startTime` and `endTime` properties in ISO format for a project I am currently working on. Here is a sample:

```
list = [
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T10:00:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T10:30:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T10:35:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T11:00:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T11:45:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:15:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:10:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:25:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:20:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:45:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:40:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T13:00:00.000Z'
 }
]
```

And I have an object `assignment` which has two properties like the objects of the `list` array above.

```
const assignment = {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:00:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:30:00.000Z'
}
```

My task is to filter the objects from the `list` array which do not fall into the interval/overlap with the `assignment`. For example, I want to include the following in my `result` array because they do not overlap/inside the interval of the `assignment`:

```
const result = [
  {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T10:00:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T10:30:00.000Z'
  },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T10:35:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T11:00:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:40:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T13:00:00.000Z'
 }
]
```

But I want to exclude the following from my `result` array because they overlap/inside the interval of the `assignment` object.

```
[
  {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T11:45:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:15:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:10:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:25:00.000Z'
 },
 {
   startTime: '2022-06-26T12:20:00.000Z',
   endTime: '2022-06-26T12:45:00.000Z'
 },
]
```

This is my idea so far:
So, there are basically 5 scenarios.

```
Scenario 1: startTime and endTime of a list object are before the startTime of assignment
Scenario 2: startTime of a list object is before the startTime of the assignment but endTime is after startTime and before endTime of the assignment
Scenario 3: startTime and endTime of a list object falls entirely into the interval of the startTime and endTime of the assignment object
Scenario 4: startTime of a list object is after the startTime and before the endTime of assignment but endTime(list object) is after the endTime of the assignment  
Scenario 5: Both startTime and endTime of the list object are after the endTime of the assignment
```

Other than writing a lot of `if-else` conditions, what is the best approach to filter the list of objects?
I am using Javascript with luxon library. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that the intervals don't overlap by checking that the `endTime` in `list` is before the `startTime` in `assignment`, or that the `startTime` in `list` is after the `endTime` in `assignment`:

```js
list = [
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T10:00:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T10:30:00.000Z' },
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T10:35:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T11:00:00.000Z' },
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T11:45:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T12:15:00.000Z' },
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T12:10:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T12:25:00.000Z' },
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T12:20:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T12:45:00.000Z' },
 { startTime: '2022-06-26T12:40:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T13:00:00.000Z' }
]

const assignment = { startTime: '2022-06-26T12:00:00.000Z', endTime: '2022-06-26T12:30:00.000Z' }

const aDates = { 
  startTime: new Date(assignment.startTime),
  endTime: new Date(assignment.endTime)
}

const result = list.filter(({ startTime, endTime }) => 
  new Date(startTime) > aDates.endTime ||
  new Date(endTime) < aDates.startTime
)

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height:100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Note I've converted the dates in `assignment` to `Date` outside the loop to save the conversion happening multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. Did not think it would be so simple. I am accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Luxon's tool for this is the Interval, which has `overlaps()`

```js
const fromISOs = (start, end) => {
  const startDt = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(start);
  const endDt = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(end);
  return luxon.Interval.fromDateTimes(startDt, endDt);
};

const assignment = fromISOs('2022-06-26T12:00:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T12:30:00.000Z');

const ranges = [
 ['2022-06-26T10:00:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T10:30:00.000Z'],
 ['2022-06-26T10:35:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T11:00:00.000Z'],
 ['2022-06-26T11:45:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T12:15:00.000Z'],
 ['2022-06-26T12:10:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T12:25:00.000Z'],
 ['2022-06-26T12:20:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T12:45:00.000Z'],
 ['2022-06-26T12:40:00.000Z', '2022-06-26T13:00:00.000Z']
];

 ranges
   .map(([start, end]) => fromISOs(start, end)) // create intervals
   .filter(i => !i.overlaps(assignment)) // filter out the overlaps
   .forEach(i => console.log(i.toISO())) // print the interval ISO (you don't have to do this)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.4.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```